# Why does $\vec{V_1}\times\vec{V_2}\cdot \overrightarrow{M_1M_2}\neq0$ imply that the two lines with $V_1$ and $V_2$ as direction vectors are skew?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

How come that when we want to prove that two lines are skew (that is that they don't intersect nor that they are parallel) we show that $C:=\vec{V_{1}} \times \vec{V_{2}} \cdot \overrightarrow{M_{1}M_{2}}\neq0 $? I understand that the main intent is to show that the parallelepiped these vectors create has volume, but still it is somewhat vague to me. ($V_{1} , V_{2}$ direction vectors, $M_{1},M_{2}$ dots on the two lines).

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6):

To prevent this question from going to waste in the unanswered queue:

- If the two lines are parallel, then $\vec {V_1}\times \vec{V_2}=0\implies C= 0$.
- If the two lines intersect, then $\vec{V_1}\times \vec{V_2}$ is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ $\implies C= 0$.
- If the two lines are skew, then $\vec{V_1}\times\vec{V_2}$ is nonzero and not perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ $\implies C\neq 0$.