# If two lines are skew, then $\overrightarrow{PQ}\cdot\left(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}\right)\neq0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Suppose two lines are described by the vector equations:

$$\mathbf{r}=\overrightarrow{OP}+\lambda\mathbf{u} \hspace{10pt} \text{and} \hspace{10pt}\mathbf{r}=\overrightarrow{OQ}+\lambda\mathbf{v} \hspace{10pt} \left(\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\right),$$

where $P$ and $Q$ are points and $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are non-zero vectors (called the lines' direction vectors).

I believe the following claim is true:

**Claim.** *If $\overrightarrow{PQ}\cdot\left(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}\right)\neq0$, then the two lines are skew.*

But is its converse true:

**Conjecture.** *If the two lines are skew, then $\overrightarrow{PQ}\cdot\left(\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}\right)\neq0$.*

---

(**Definition.** Two lines are *skew* if they do not intersect and are not parallel.

**Definition.** Two lines are *parallel* if their direction vectors can be written as non-zero multiples of each other.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does $\vec{V_1}\times\vec{V_2}\cdot \overrightarrow{M_1M_2}\neq0$ imply that the two lines with $V_1$ and $V_2$ as direction vectors are skew?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848838/why-does-vecv-1-times-vecv-2-cdot-overrightarrowm-1m-2-neq0-imply-that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantity $\overrightarrow{PQ} \cdot (\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v})$ is known as the scalar triple product. It corresponds with the determinant of the matrix formed by putting the vectors as rows (or columns, equivalently). As such, it is $0$ if and only if the vectors are linearly dependent.

Note that, if two lines are skew, then $\mathbf{u}$ is independent from $\mathbf{v}$, that is, neither is a scalar multiple of each other. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\overrightarrow{PQ} \cdot (\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}) = 0$. Then the vectors are linearly dependent, hence
$$\overrightarrow{PQ} = a \mathbf{u} + b \mathbf{v}$$
for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the plane $\Pi$, going through $P$, generated by directions $u$ and $v$. That is,
$$\Pi = \left\lbrace \overrightarrow{OP} + \lambda \mathbf{u} + \mu \mathbf{v} : \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}\right\rbrace.$$
Then both lines lie in $\Pi$. Obviously the first line lies in $\Pi$ because we can choose $\mu = 0$. The second line lies in $\Pi$ because
$$\overrightarrow{OQ} + \lambda \mathbf{v} = \overrightarrow{OP} + \overrightarrow{PQ} + \lambda \mathbf{v} = \overrightarrow{OP} + a\mathbf{u} + (\lambda + b) \mathbf{v} \in \Pi.$$
The lines are coplanar, hence they follow the Euclidean dichotomy: they intersect or they're parallel. Either way, they're not skew, which is a contradiction.